cell 1 is not a phandle reference in fragment@0
I'm trying to compile a DTS overlay file, unfortunately I am facing this error.

root@pc-debian:/home/zyssai/odroid/compiler/linux# make dtbs

scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig

  CHK     include/config/kernel.release

  CHK     include/config/kernel.release_full

  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h

  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h

  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h

  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h

  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h

  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh

  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h

  DTCO    arch/arm64/boot/dts/amlogic/overlays/odroidn2/keymatrix.dtbo

arch/arm64/boot/dts/amlogic/overlays/odroidn2/keymatrix.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Property 'col-gpios', cell 1 is not a phandle reference in /fragment@0/__overlay__/matrix-keypad

arch/arm64/boot/dts/amlogic/overlays/odroidn2/keymatrix.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Could not get phandle node for /fragment@0/__overlay__/matrix-keypad:col-gpios(cell 1)

arch/arm64/boot/dts/amlogic/overlays/odroidn2/keymatrix.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Property 'row-gpios', cell 1 is not a phandle reference in /fragment@0/__overlay__/matrix-keypad

arch/arm64/boot/dts/amlogic/overlays/odroidn2/keymatrix.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Could not get phandle node for /fragment@0/__overlay__/matrix-keypad:row-gpios(cell 1)

root@pc-debian:/home/zyssai/odroid/compiler/linux#

Here is DTS file.
/dts-v1/;

/plugin/;



#include <dt-bindings/gpio/meson-g12a-gpio.h>

#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>



/{

        fragment@0 {

                target-path = "/";



                __overlay__ {

                        matrix_keypad: matrix-keypad {

                                compatible = "gpio-matrix-keypad";

                                col-gpios = <

                                        &gpio GPIOA_12 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        &gpio GPIOX_9 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        &gpio GPIOX_2 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        &gpio GPIOX_1 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        >;

                                row-gpios = <

                                        &gpio GPIOA_4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        &gpio GPIOX_4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        &gpio GPIOX_0 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        &gpio GPIOX_8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH

                                        >;

                                /* sample keymap */

                                linux,keymap = <

                                        0x00000052 /* row 0, col 0, KEY_KP0 */

                                        0x0001004f /* row 0, col 1, KEY_KP1 */

                                        0x00020050 /* row 0, col 2, KEY_KP2 */

                                        0x00030051 /* row 0, col 3, KEY_KP3 */

                                        0x0100004b /* row 1, col 0, KEY_KP4 */

                                        0x0101004c /* row 1, col 1, KEY_KP5 */

                                        0x0102004d /* row 1, col 2, KEY_KP6 */

                                        0x01030047 /* row 1, col 3, KEY_KP7 */

                                        0x02000048 /* row 2, col 0, KEY_KP8 */

                                        0x02010049 /* row 2, col 1, KEY_KP9 */

                                        0x0202004a /* row 2, col 2, KEY_KPMINUS */

                                        0x0203004e /* row 2, col 3, KEY_KPPLUS */

                                        0x03000053 /* row 3, col 0, KEY_KPDOT */

                                        0x0301006e /* row 3, col 1, KEY_INSERT */

                                        0x03020075 /* row 3, col 2, KEY_KPEQUAL */

                                        0x03030079 /* row 3, col 3, KEY_KPCOMMA */

                                        >;

                                gpio-activelow;

                                debounce-delay-ms = <100>;

                col-scan-delay-us = <500>;

                col-switch-delay-ms = <20>;

                linux,no-autorepeat;

            };

        };

    };

};


This is a key matrix array, the purpose is to use up to 16 buttons with only 8 wires, going to gpio of Odroid N2.
Actually the file is working, but I am facing error with some combination of row/col.
I tried different combinations, I'm sure gpio pins are not used for something else.
